# Answer an incoming call by a sip account programatically using AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I use asterisk in my project and users login with softphones. I want to grant a person to forward an incoming call to another user's sip account by clicking on a button and answer the call immediately so that the user will be able to start talking with caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need read documentation for you softphones/hardphones. Usualy need add sip header Call-Info: answer-after=0.

So you plan can be

1. Check if auto-answer/intercom posible with your softphone or hardphone.
2. Create dialplan which will add header and call
3. Transfer call to that dialplan using AMI Transfer command

For more info check this:

http://icesupport.ingeniussoftware.com/customer/portal/articles/990030-asterisk-auto-answer-on-originate

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Transfer

Comment: Thanks a lot @arheops, Do you know how can i enable auto answer on qutecom ?

Comment: No.First time hear about that brand. Try default method, if not work call support.